# Angular - Mock new Audio() with Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular service that plays a sound on a certain condition. I would like to mock the `window`'s `Audio` class to spy on the `play` function to check if it's actually called.

Here is my class:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { SoundPreferencesStore } from "app/shared/stores/sound-preferences.store";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class Service {
    private readonly _audioPath: string = "assets/sounds/sound.mp3";
    private readonly _audio: HTMLAudioElement;

    public isSoundMuted: boolean;

    constructor(
        private readonly _soundPreferencesStore: SoundPreferencesStore
    ) {
        this._audio = new Audio(this._audioPath);
        this.isSoundMuted = this._soundPreferencesStore.isSoundMuted();
    }

    public playSound(): void {
        if (!this.isSoundMuted) {
            this._audio.play().catch(() => {});
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to mock the `Audio` class to check if the `play` function was called when I call the `playSound` function in my service using Jasmine like so:

```
describe("playSound", () => {
    it("should play sound", async () => {
        // Arrange
        // Here is where I would use the mock
        const audioMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<Audio>(["play"]);
        service.isSoundMuted = false;

        // Act
        service.playSound();

        // Assert
        expect(audioMock.play).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could try testing if `play()` was called if you would add some sort of a flag in the service, you can't mock a class property, and you cannot even access a `private` one from outside, even in the test service itself.

Probably there is a better, clever way but, I would test it like the following:

**Service**

```
@Injectable({...})
export class Service {
  ... 
  ...
  public playWasTriggered = false;
  
  ...

  public playSound(): void {
    if (!this.isSoundMuted) {
      this.playWasTriggered = true;
      this._audio.play().catch(() => {});
    } else this.playWasTriggered = false;
  }
}
```

**Spec**

```js
describe('Service', () => {
  let service: Service;
  const mockSoundService = jasmine.createSpyObj<SoundPreferencesStore>('SoundPreferencesStore', ['isSoundMuted']);

  // it will play a sound since it returns TRUE
  beforeEach(() => mockSoundService.isSoundMuted.and.returnValue(true))

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{ provide: SoundPreferencesStore, useValue: mockSoundService }]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(Service);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('plays a sound', () => {
     component.playSound();
     expect(component.playWasTriggered).toBe(true);
  });
}
```